# How to add multiple dictionaries together from a dictionary generator to create single collated python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, generator, dictionary-comprehension

I am asking for help in doing this the pythonic way.

My code so far.
I created a generator to create a dictionary with a tuple as a key linking to the objects I want to use later in my project.
I am sure that there is a better way to do this. My attempts as dictionary and list comprehension have not succeeded.

```
app = models.get_app('djangoapp')
appmodels = models.get_models(app)

gen = mapEntGen(appmodels)  
d = {}  
for x in gen:  
    d.update(x)
```

To make it more clear what my objects look like.

```
for x in gen:
    print(x)

{('in', 1): <class 'djangoapp.models.entrance01IN'>}
{('out', 1): <class 'djangoapp.models.entrance01OUT'>}
{('in', 2): <class 'djangoapp.models.entrance02IN'>}
{('out', 2): <class 'djangoapp.models.entrance02OUT'>}
...
```

These are my failed attempts at comprehension

```
{d: aDict for aDict in mapEntGen(appmodels)}  
d = {key: value for (key, value) in gen}  
d = {key: value for (key, value) in mapEntGen(appmodels[1:])}
```

I believe the problem is most likely that it is already a dictionary and not two other types. That can be used as a key value pair.

```
----> 1 for k, v in gen:
      2     d[k] = v
      3 

ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

This is the other code I am using for my generator to build a map of objects and the keys for finding them.

```
def mapEntGen(EntranceObj = []):    
    for x in EntranceObj:
        thisEnt = (x._meta.verbose_name[10:],
                   int(x._meta.verbose_name[8:10]))
        aDict = {thisEnt : x}
        yield aDict
```

It may seem like a duplicate but nothing I have tried is working as per all the examples I have tried so far.

Comment: Maybe I should simplify my generator to yield the key value pair. But that seams back wards as I am working with dictionaries there should be some way to just expand the dictionary.

Comment: does update not work or do you have duplicate keys that you need to update your values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to give a totally different direction to your code, which might be more readable, and useable, depending on the rest of your code:

Instead of mapGenEnt, let's create two separate generators from appModels (whatever that is):

1. A list of codes (that you later use as keys, such as `('out', 1)`.
2. A list of actual objects/models (that you later use as values, such as `<class 'djangoapp.models.entrance01IN'>`.

So, let's say you have these two generators:

```
def code_names(EntranceObj):
   return ((entrance._meta.verbose_name[10:], int(entrance._meta.verbose_name[8:10]) for entrance in EntranceObj)

def entries(EntranceObj):
   return EntranceObj    # Shorter than: (entrance for entrance in EntranceObj)
```

Now we have two functions who clearly do their own thing, and we have to create `d`. Easy, using [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) or [`itertools.izip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip):

```
d = dict(zip(code_names(appmodels), entries(appmodels)))
```

---

To improve readability a bit more, I would personally give this function a name like `generate_model_entries(appmodels)`:

```
def generate_model_entries(models):
    return dict(zip(code_names(models), entries(models)))

d = generate_model_entries(appmodels)
```

*PS: If you have a more accurate name than `x` for your loop variables, please; use it.*

Comment: Since you are giving tips on readability *Function names should be lowercase, with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability*

Comment: Thanks Padraic, you're absolutely right. Was working with Java yesterday so shame on me ;) Editted.

Comment: I choose your answer as it created much better code. Every thing is easier to read and understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to answer your problem as it is displayed here would be to discard the mapEntGen, and to do:

```
d = {((x._meta.verbose_name[10:],
       int(x._meta.verbose_name[8:10])):x 
           for x in EntranceObj}
```

There's no need to create different dictionaries and then to combine them.

---

If you're keen on using the generator - why have it return a dictionary, when the dictionary only has a single key and value? Have it return a tuple:

```
def mapEntGen(EntranceObj = []):    
    for x in EntranceObj:
        thisEnt = (x._meta.verbose_name[10:],
                   int(x._meta.verbose_name[8:10]))
        yield (thisEnt, x)
```

and then getting `d` is easy:

```
d = dict(mapEntGen(appmodels))
```

---

If you want to use **your** generator:

`mapEntGen(appmodels)` generates dictionaries - treat them as such. When you want to iterate their items you have to call iteritems, and iterate them. This should work:

```
d = {key:value for subdct in gen for key, value in subdct.iteritems()}
```

Just to make sure you understand the comprehension, this is the equivalent of doing:

```
d = {}
for subdct in gen:
    for key, value in subdct.iteritems():
        d[key] = value
```

(of course `gen` can be replaced with `mapEntGen(appmodels)`)